# How to read the .sif files using pyspark

Tags: python, java, pyspark, file-io

How can I read the hetionet-v1.0-edges.sif.gz file using pyspark?

```
url = "https://github.com/hetio/hetionet/raw/master/hetnet/tsv/hetionet-v1.0-edges.sif.gz"
response = requests.get(url)
content = io.BytesIO(response.content)


edges_df = spark.read.format("csv") \
    .option("delimiter", "\t") \
    .option("inferSchema", "true") \
    .option("header", "true") \
    .load(gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=content)) \
```

Error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.String in pyspark

Please suggest the format to be used